# How do I get a String from XML by name reference?

Tags: android

I'm trying do something like this

```
public class CytatCore {

    public static void cytatCore(int number, TextView tv) {

       tv.setText(R.string.text+number);
    }
}
```

I've a lot of string in xml named e.g "text1", "text2" etc. Only last value is changing. I tried to do this in couple ways, but I still get errors in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to accomplish because your question is not written clearly, but I'll take a stab in the dark and assume your question is

> How do I append a number onto the end of a string I have in XML?

**Edit:** My assumption was wrong, it appears your question is rather

> How do I get a String from XML by name reference?

Using the `getIdentifier()` method of a `Context` will look up an ID by name...but be warned that this operation is not recommended if it's used extremely often, as it's slow.

```
public class CytatCore {

    public static void cytatCore(Context context, int number, TextView tv) {

       int textId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("text" + number, "string", context.getPackageName());
       tv.setText(textId);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, in xml file i've something like this `<string name="text1">Some text</string> ` and `<string name="text2">Some text2</string> ` and i want to choose one, and which it will be selected depends on `int number`

Comment: Thanks you helped a lot :) I had long pause in programming for android.

Answer (score 3):

I think followin code wil work for you

```
switch(number) {
    case 1 : tv.setText(R.string.text1);
    case 2 : tv.setText(R.string.text2);
}
```

while using this type code, put also text1, text2 in your R.string; switch case also processed faster.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to to avoid this :P That's why I write here :D

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is to get a reference to the `Resources` object and use the method [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). If you are in an activity then you could do:

```
public void cytatCore(int number, TextView tv) {    
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("text" + 1, "string", this.getPackageName());
    t.setText(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the names in an array:

```
...
private String[] ids = new String[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    ids[i] = context.getString(R.string.resource_name) + i;
}
```

and then:

```
...
public static void cytatCore(int i, TextView tv) {
    tv.setText(ids[i]);
}
```

or simply:

```
    ...
public static void cytatCore(int i, TextView tv) {
    tv.setText(context.getString(R.string.resource_name) + i);
}
```

Comment: This wont work because "text" is a variable name not a real string name that you can dynamically change

Comment: I know i can do it in that way (or something similar), but I'm looking for the simplest way :)

Comment: You have to remove at least the first sample from your post and the last one still could return unexpected strings if you don't put the strings in order..